# Query for an employee's idle time

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am very beginner in PhP Please help me to complete below requirement.

I have a database table which have

```
EMPLOYEECODE JOBCODE STARTTIME(in float)  ENDTIME(in float)
1001          01       09.5101                12.1545
1001          01       13.255                 14.525
1001          02       15.000                 16.525
1002          01       09.000                 12.1058
1002          02       13.00                  17.1254
```

I want to get each employe idle time on each jobs and total idle time of the employee that would show something like below table

```
EMPLOYEECODE  JOBCODE   IdleTime(HH:MM)   TotalIdleTime(HH:MM)
1001           01           ?                     ?
1001           01           ?                     ?
1001           02           ?                     ?
1002           01           ?                     ?
1002           02           ?                     ?
```

in above table data will show something like

```
EMPLOYEECODE  JOBCODE                  IdleTime(HH:MM)           TotalIdleTime(HH:MM)
1001           (last worked)02         idle time on last job     total idle time of 1001
```

on all jobs

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: `IdleTime === ENDTIME - STARTTIME`, right?

Comment: Answer to "Employee Idle time" was about 20 seconds in your case to write the OP!

Comment: i'm fairly sure if you monitor how long someone idles in milliseconds and penalise them, they'll either resent you or leave.

Answer (score 1):

The below query is for `MySQL` only as it abuses the fact that `MySQL` always picks the first (rather than an arbitrarily positioned) value of **nonaggregated columns** (hence the inner `ORDER BY`), let alone the possibility to even `SELECT` the latter.

Please [see this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91f0a/5):

```
  SELECT x.EMPLOYEECODE
       , MAX(x.JOBCODE) AS JOBCODE
       , x.IdleTime
       , SUM(x.IdleTime) AS TotalIdleTime
    FROM ( SELECT EMPLOYEECODE
                , JOBCODE
                , SUM(ENDTIME - STARTTIME) AS IdleTime
             FROM employee
         GROUP BY EMPLOYEECODE, JOBCODE
         ORDER BY EMPLOYEECODE ASC, JOBCODE DESC ) AS x
GROUP BY x.EMPLOYEECODE
ORDER BY x.EMPLOYEECODE ASC
```

And this is what the documentation has to say:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group.
>
> **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values the server chooses.**

The second paragraph (emphasized by me) would seem to contradict my statement but I've never encountered a result that wouldn't follow the above mentioned rule (i.e. picking the first value available). Besides the inner `ORDER BY` does happen to occur BEFORE the outer selection takes place, and thus allows the query to return the correct value.